# inheriting property from a base class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

I have a question about inheriting properties from a base class (see sample code below).  Can I create an instance of ParentClass, assign a value to BaseString, and then later on create an instance of ChildClass that could read the value of BaseString that I assigned to the instance of ParentClass?  Or is that bad programming?

I ask this because I have a scenario where I have a form with 10 or so inputs that I have assigned to a parent class (because I don't know which child class I will use at the time) when the user hits submit.  Later on when I figure out which specific child of the parent class to use, I create an instance of the child class but can't figure out if there is a way to pass a reference of the parent class to be able to read the properties from the parent.

```
Class ParentClass
{
    protected string BaseString {get; set;}

    public ParentClass()
    {
    }
}

Class ChildClass: ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The base string is " + this.BaseString);
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds to me like the perfect case for _composition over inheritance_.. rather than trying to model an inheritance chain then code against it.. compose objects inside others.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to create an instance of ParentClass and then turn it into an instance of ChildClass? Or do want to have a reference to a ParentClass instance in your ChildClass instance?

Comment: I want to reference the ParentClass instance in the ChildClass

Comment: @SimonWhitehead So by composition do you mean use Interfaces?